# In perl, what is more efficient way to substitute the last matching item with the newline than following?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace the

```
hi@my@name@is@foo
```

into

```
hi@my@name@is
foo
```

That is subsitute the last @ with the "\n" character. Here's my tentative solution, but I feel this can be done much better.

```
echo "hi@my@name@is@foo"| perl -pe '$_ = reverse($_);s/@/\n/;$_=reverse($_)'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl 5.10.0 and up, you can use [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions), which is effectively a variable-length look-behind:

```
echo "hi@my@name@is@foo"| perl -pe 's/.*\K@/\n/'
```

Comment: Oh, was that 5.10? I had 5.14 in my head.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, although I had to double check the docs to be sure. I always forget which feature was implemented when.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(.*)` to capture everything up to the last `@` since it is greedy.

```
s/(.*)@/\1\n/
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the negative lookahead:

```
echo "hi@my@name@is@foo"| perl -pe 's/@(?!.*@)/\n/'
```

… but okay, `\K` is shorter still. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is rindex

```
 echo "hi@my@name@is@foo" | perl -ne ' $cnt=rindex($_,"@");
 print substr($_,0,$cnt)."\n".substr($_,$cnt+1)."\n";'
```

Comment: In general, it's best to avoid magic numbers like 13. Also, `substr` can do replacements if you pass a fourth parameter or use it as an l-value: `perl -pe '$pos = rindex($_, "@"); substr($_, $pos, 1) = "\n" if $pos >= 0'`

Comment: Much to write, and much to read … a hard-coded 13 that should be $cnt demonstrating that it is hard to write as well … and an extra newline to boot … how about `echo "hi@my@name@is@foo" | perl -pe 'substr($_,rindex($_,"@"),1,"\n")'`

Comment: @TheSidhekin , my fault . i forgot to replace 13 with $cnt.

Comment: @TheSidhekin That replaces the last character with a `\n` if the string contains no `@`: `echo -n foo | perl -pe 'substr($_, rindex($_, "@"), 1, "\n")'` prints `fo`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, it assumes there _is_ a "last @".  As does michael501's original solution.  See my answer (not comment) for my preferred solution(s). :)